# How to remove space from a String?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to do removing space (`" "`) from a string without using the `strip` function. How to implement `if 'head' == " "` (space) in the program?

```
skipSpaces :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
skipSpaces [] = []
skipSpaces (h:t)
| h `elem` " "    = skipSpaces t -- condition if 'head' is equal to " "(space),do nothing. 
| otherwise       = h : skipSpaces t -- produce the result
```

I don't know how to declare about`if 'head' == " "` (space)
nor `if 'head' == "(contain_strings)"(a collection of letters)"`.

Example:
Input: `"I am twenty one"`
Output Expectation: `"Iamtwentyone"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the space directly:

```
skipSpaces [] = []
skipSpaces (' ':t) = skipSpaces t
skipSpaces (h:t) = h : skipSpaces t
```

One trick, though, is to think about what *function* to apply to `skipSpaces t`, depending on the value of `h`. Consider a slight modification of the above:

```
skipSpaces [] = []
skipSpaces (' ':t) = id (skipSpaces t)
skipSpaces (h:t) = (h :) (skipSpaces t)
```

Note the similarity between the last two cases. We can factor out the recursive call as follows:

```
skipSpaces [] = []
skipSpaces (h:t) = (if h == ' ' then id else (h :)) (skipSpaces t)
```

Comment: Thankyou, but how to declare h == 'collection of letters'.

Comment: You don't need that for this function. Keep in mind the difference between `' ' :: Char` and `" " :: [Char]`.